# How to increment multiple values in a while loop using stored procedures?

Tags: sql, loops, stored-procedures

I am really new in SQL, but this is what I have so far:

```
Alter Procedure GetallSchedule(@ScreenKey INT,@ShowNo INT) As
BEGIN
--DECLARE @ScreenKey INT
--DECLARE @ShowNo INT
--Declare @j INT
--Declare @i INT

Insert into Schedule(Cineplex,
ScreenKey,ShowOrder,ShowNo,FilmKey,ShowDate,ShowTime)
Values (1,@ScreenKey,1,@ShowNo,100,GETDATE(),GETDATE())

SET @ShowNo = 1
SET @ScreenKey = 1
WHILE (@ScreenKey <=20)
  BEGIN
    WHILE (@ShowNo <=7)
      BEGIN
         Insert into Schedule(
             Cineplex,
             ScreenKey,ShowOrder,ShowNo,FilmKey,ShowDate,ShowTime)
           Values (1,@ScreenKey,1,@ShowNo,100,GETDATE(),GETDATE())
         SET @ShowNo = @ShowNo + 1
      END
    SET @ScreenKey = @ScreenKey + 1
  END

END

go

--Execute GetallSchedule 'TUC'
```

Here I need to insert the values incrementing both the `Screenkey` and `ShowNo`. I need to get the results for 20 screens with 7 shows each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ShowNo` variable needs to be reset to 1 before each run of the inner While loop. Move one line down a bit...

```
SET @ScreenKey = 1
WHILE (@ScreenKey <=20)
  BEGIN
    SET @ShowNo = 1  -- this one -- reset to 1 before using in loop
    WHILE (@ShowNo <=7)
      BEGIN
         Insert into Schedule....
```

As you had it, the variable ended up looping though its range just once, and never got a chance to do its work again.